# How can I more quickly process a 13,665,600 row CSV file (that I've already uploaded to a database) with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, data-science

I have a csv file of weather data taken at 390 different locations at 15 minute intervals across an entire year. I uploaded it to a local SQLite database in an attempt to make processing it easier.

Now I'm trying to calculate the daily average temperature of 193 of these locations for the entire year and output that as a json file but I'm having a lot of trouble coding a function that can do so in a reasonable amount of time.

This is what I have so far:

```
def getMeanWeather(coords):
    data = {coord: {} for coord in coords}
    def analyze(start, end):
        for month in range(start, end):
            for day in range(1, 32):
                currDay = f"2015-{str(month).zfill(2)}-{str(day).zfill(2)}"
                df = fetch.getWeather(usecols='temp,lat,lon', datetime=currDay, coordinates=coords)
                if not df.empty:
                    for coord in coords:
                        data[coord][curr_day] = df[(df['lat'] == coord[0]) & (df['lon'] == coord[1])]['temp'].mean()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=analyze(1, 3), name="t1")
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=analyze(3, 5), name="t2")
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=analyze(5, 7), name="t3")
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=analyze(7, 9), name="t4")
    t5 = threading.Thread(target=analyze(9, 11), name="t5")
    t6 = threading.Thread(target=analyze(11, 13), name="t6")

    threads = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    return data
```

In summary, my code creates a dataframe of the daily weather for all 193 locations and then iterates through these locations and takes the mean of the sub-dataframe of rows with the correct coordinates. `data` is dictionary I intend to dump into a json file.

`coords` is a list of the 193 coordinates as tuples.

`fetch` is a module I wrote to allow me to abstract the need to write SQL queries and fetch data from my database as I need it. I naively started to use the threading library in an attempt to speed things up but that isn't helping much either.

I've ran similar code for a single coordinate and for stats regarding all 390 locations together as opposed to some individually. In these cases, the code takes roughly 10 minutes to run. Not that bad in my opinion but definitely not feasible once I up the scale to 193 locations.

My table looks something like this:

```
|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
|   date         |     temp       |      lat       |     lon        |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
|2015-01-01 0:00 |      67        |      30        |     -90        |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
```

And continues on with 390 different latitudes and longitudes for each time and then new measurements with the same 390 coordinates for every 15 minutes.

I'm expecting output in the following format:

```
data = {(lat_1, lon_1):{"2015-01-01": 26.03372999919653,
                        "2015-01-02": 31.196771341785723,
                               ⋮
                        "2015-12-31": 40.02},
               ⋮
         (lat_193, lon_193):{...}
        }
```

I'm at a loss as to what I can do to make this code smarter and faster and would appreciate any advice. Also would love some tips on why what I'm doing doesn't work so that I can learn from that.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not doing this calculation directly in SQLite?  Can you include the table structure, some sample data, and the expected output?

Comment: I'm not doing it directly in SQLite because I didn't know I could / don't know how to because I'm learning learning on the fly :)

Comment: No...do _not_ include your data here.  Instead, _edit_ your question and show the table structure, along with the expected output.

Comment: Wow, I just looked into the SQLite AVG() function and I feel silly. I'm pretty sure that alone will suit my needs

Comment: This is also my feeling `:-)` ... no sense in loading your table into SQLite and then trying to use Python to do reporting.

Comment: sounds like you should be using groupby and aggregating as mean